# Use a generic method for an unknown class?

Tags: c#, methods

Here what I want to do using C#:

```
unknownClass handle;

if(blabla)
    handle = new A();
else
    handle = new B();

handle.CommonMethod();
```

Obviously, classes A and B both have the method `CommonMethod`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the implementation of classes A and B? In other words, they are not part of some library that you have no control over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface for this job:

```
interface ICommon
    {
        void CommonMethod();
    }

    public class A : ICommon  
    { 
        //implement CommonMethod 
    }

    public class B : ICommon 
    { 
        //implement CommonMethod 
    }
```

then:

```
ICommon handle;

if(blabla)
   handle = new A();
else
   handle = new B();

handle.CommonMethod();
```

Comment: this solution can be extended by using the factory (factory design pattern) to decide which object to create.

Answer (score 7):

Have both `A` and `B` implement an interface that has a method, `CommonMethod`.  Use that interface in place of `unknownClass`.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you should use interfaces.
Example:

```
public interface IBarking{
   public void Barks();
}

public class Dog : IBarking{
  //some specific dog properties
  public void Barks(){
    string sound = "Bark";
  }
}


public class Wolf : IBarking{
  //some specific wolf properties
  public void Barks(){
    string sound = "Woof";
  }
}

//and your implementation here:

IBarking barkingAnimal;
if (isDog){
  barkingAnimal = new Dog();
}
else {
  barkingAnimal = new Wolf();
}
barkingAnimal.Barks();
```

Answer (score 1):

An interface or common base-class should always be the preferred option here. I would actually introduce an interface and wrapper classes for each concrete type if I needed. When **no other option is possible**, though:

```
dynamic obj = ...
obj.CommonMethod(); // this is a hack
```

But: do everything else first. Like I say: wrapper types would be preferable if you can't edit the objects themselves:

```
IFoo obj;
...
obj = new BarWrapper(new Bar());
...
obj.CommonMethod();
```